# Facebook Marketing API - time_range

Tags: facebook-marketing-api

Following the doc here

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-campaign-group/insights/

I'm querying insights on ad performance etc. However, I can't make the time_frame work. A query like this

[https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/_CAMPAIGN_ID_/insights?access_token=*AT*&time_range&since=2015-11-08&until=2015-11-12](https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/_CAMPAIGN_ID_/insights?access_token=_AT_&time_range&since=2015-11-08&until=2015-11-12)

just returns lifetime stats. I've tried to modify the query in many ways, but it's always an error or lifetime.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I imagine you've found the answer by now but this could help someone else as from experience the documentation isn't always the most friendly to jump into.

You'll need to format it as a time_range object, the example object below is from that page of the documentation you included. It's essentially just an object with 2 properties- since and until.

```
{'since'=>YYYY-MM-DD,'until'=>YYYY-MM-DD}
```

So from the example URL you're using, rather than setting the *since* and *until* values using individual parameters, the time range would be set like this (I've URL encoded the object):

time_range=%7B%22since%22%3A%22**YYYY-MM-DD**%22%2C%22until%22%3A%22**YYYY-MM-DD**%22%7D

Comment: Excellent! Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Hi! is there a  way to include hours and minutes to the date range format?

Comment: Should work like this: "YYYY-MM-DDT23:59:59".
Note: I haven't tried this myself.

Comment: Using `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss` does not appear to work.  I tried it and received this error: `(#100) Must be a date representation in the format YYYY-MM-DD"`.

Answer (score 4):

Another alternative is to pass the `time_range` object as below if you don't want to encode the `URL` and want to keep the URL clean.

Facebook is smart enough to parse the URL and set the correct `time_range`.

```
https://httpbin.org/get?time_range[since]=2019-08-10&time_range[until]=2019-09-09
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are doing this in the Graph API Explorer, it should be like below:

1. Work: time_range={since:'2021-05-01',until:'2021-05-05'}
2. NOT Work: time_range={'since':2021-05-01,'until':2021-05-05}

I get #2 syntax from Facebook's document itself :|

Comment: *If you are doing this in the Graph API Explorer*, maybe, but they aren't.

Answer (score 3):

yes Facebook didn't provide good document for this. I also struggled a lot. we can use time range to fetch the data for specific date or date range.

Inside Graph API you can provide like below 
me?fields=id,name,adaccounts{campaigns{adsets{ads{insights.time_range({'since':'2020-05-01','until':'2020-05-01'}){adset_id,campaign_id,ad_id,clicks}}}}}

note the syntax from insights.time_range({'since':'2020-05-01','until':'2020-05-01'}).

once you provide above code and submit, fb provides the codes for different languages such as JavaScript, ios , android etc.

curl will looks like below

curl -i -X GET \
"https://graph.facebook.com/v6.0/me?fields=id%2Cname%2Cadaccounts%7Bcampaigns%7Badsets%7Bads%7Binsights.time_range(%7B'since'%3A'2020-05-01'%2C'until'%3A'2020-05-01'%7D)%7Badset_id%2Ccampaign_id%2Cad_id%2Cclicks%7D%7D%7D%7D%7D&access_token="

Answer (score 0):

As none of the solutions mentioned above worked for me, although it is a very very late response. How I tried is below:

```
dates = 'since='+start_date+'&until='+end_date

requests.get("https://graph.facebook.com/" + BusinessManagerConfig.version + key + \
                               "/insights?metric=" + ','.join(BusinessManagerConfig.metrics) + \
                           "&period=day&" + dates + \
                               "&access_token="+page_token + '&limit=5')
```

I hope it helps others

Answer (score 0):

This one gets me every time. Here's a URL that worked in the Graph API.

```
act_2222222/insights?fields=unique_actions,actions&level=account&time_ranges=[{since:'2020-06-12',until:'2020-06-12'}]
```

2222222 is your ad account

Answer (score 0):

I kept getting an HTML error page as a response until I finally realized that a space after the comma was making this API unhappy.

"time_range={since:'2020-06-12',until:'2020-06-14'}"
works fine.

"time_range={since:'2020-06-12', until:'2020-06-14'}"
causes much suffering.